# Sorting with hibernate single table inheritance strategy

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, single-table-inheritance

In my application I have three entities, BaseNotification as a parent and SmsNotification and EmailNotification as child entities which extend BaseNotification.

I am using hibernate single table inheritance strategy so all attributes fit into one table.

Lets say I have some common attributes on BaseNotification entity, and child entities have one specific attribute each (SmsNotification has mobileNumber and EmailNotification has email attribute).

```
public abstract class BaseNotification implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
...
}

public abstract class EmailNotification extends BaseNotification implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
...
}

public abstract class SmsNotification extends BaseNotification implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "mobileNumber")
    private String mobileNumber;
...
}
```

Is there a way of fetching all notifications with all attributes while sorting on child attributes (for example by email) in one go with spring rest?

Comment: Looks like you need one common Notification entity.

Comment: @StanislavL I have it already, it is BaseNotification.